# How to run a matlab file from c# user interface

Tags: c#, matlab

I have a C# application that creates a user interface and a matlab function in an m-file. What I need to do is, when the C# application has compiled successfully and opened the user interface, I press a button on the interface and it makes matlab run the m-file while also performing the task the button-press event is supposed to do. The purpose is to run both the C# application and matlab function at the same time (synchronise).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is your matlab function:

```
function [output] = YourMatlabFunction( Input )
   %
   % your code here
   %
end
```

Then you can write in your C# code:

```
Type MatlabType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Matlab.Desktop.Application");
Matlab.MLApp matlab = (MLApp.MLApp)Activator.CreateInstance(MatlabType);

matlabGoTo = "cd " + "('" + pathOfYourFile + "')"; 
matlab.Execute(@matlabGoTo);

object result = null;
matlab.Feval("YourMatlabFunction", 1, out result, input);
object[] res = result as object[];
```

To keep your processes run parallel you can use the the `Invoke`commands. This will execute your actions parallel. Here is the link to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel(v=vs.110).aspx).